# Table - User controlled content with specific layout/styling based on the content entered

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html-table, explode

**UPDATE:** I decided to go a different route and rework the table structure itself, and use PHP to scan the td cells, then add some custom div tags surrounding the internal elements when special characters are found. The divs allow for the full height within each td cell. And, this also allows for the flexibility of having multiple possible columns, given the tables were being generated by the user using a table builder, which only offers control of adding full rows / full columns, not sub-dividing the td cells.

I'm sure there are more efficient ways of doing this PHP check if anyone's willing to share, but the following works.

Essentially, checking through all td cells within the table, and looking for 4 possible scenarios of special characters.

"1,000 | 1,000 | 1,000" > Would be displayed as 3 equal "cells" within that td.

"1,000 | 1,000" > Would be displayed as 2 equal "cells" within that td.

"1,000 |: 1,000" > Would be displayed as 1 "cell" at 33% and 1 "cell" 66% within that td.

"1,000 :| 1,000" > Would be displayed as 1 "cell" at 66% and 1 "cell" 33% within that td.

```
$cellcheck = $td['c'];

if (substr_count($cellcheck," | ") == 2 ) {
    $elem = explode(" | ", $cellcheck);
    echo '<td>';
    echo '<div class="elem-wrap"><div class="elem">' . $elem[0] . '</div><div class="elem">' . $elem[1] . '</div><div class="elem">' . $elem[2] . '</div></div>';
    echo '</td>';
} elseif (substr_count($cellcheck," | ") == 1 ) {
    $elem = explode(" | ", $cellcheck);
    echo '<td>';
    echo '<div class="elem-wrap"><div class="elem">' . $elem[0] . '</div><div class="elem">' . $elem[1] . '</div></div>';
    echo '</td>';
} elseif (substr_count($cellcheck," |: ") == 1 ) {
    $elem = explode(" |: ", $cellcheck);
    echo '<td>';
    echo '<div class="elem-wrap"><div class="elem">' . $elem[0] . '</div><div class="elem double">' . $elem[1] . '</div></div>';
    echo '</td>';
} elseif (substr_count($cellcheck," :| ") == 1 ) {
    $elem = explode(" :| ", $cellcheck);
    echo '<td>';
    echo '<div class="elem-wrap"><div class="elem double">' . $elem[0] . '</div><div class="elem">' . $elem[1] . '</div></div>';
    echo '</td>';
} else {
    echo '<td>'.$cellcheck.'</td>';
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/evn0jc7v/

**ORIG:** Trying to allow users to control their table cell data using a builder to achieve a specific layout - the builder doesn't allow for sub-dividing td cells, so each of these rows represent one td in each row. I'm looking for a way to allow custom layout within each td by identifying special characters as they are  entered into the cell.

Specifically, the design and alignment would look like this:
[image: the alignment is the issue]

So that users could enter the following, and that then style as shown above.

I'm using jQuery to find those internal characters |, :|, |: and then could insert some span tags in their place, but having trouble getting the spacing of the first column equal to the others above it, and still center the second number when only two values are entered in a cell.

Here is a JSFiddle that explains better: https://jsfiddle.net/wwwxydz1/1/

```
2 | 4 | 6
2,070 | 4,140 | 6,210
1,544 | 3,087 | 4,631
5.0
127
1,200 |: 1,400
1,000 |: 1,167
5.1 |: 5.9
```

Any thoughts on how to best pull this off? Thanks for any insight.

Comment: Could you make use of the colspan attribute?

Comment: looks like a good use case for css flexbox

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I created a small script using jQuery for you that does what you want I think. It converts a string to a table with your syntax. The trick is to filter each cell from your string and put it in it's own `<td>`

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/kapoko/cmx5onea/3)

Here's the code:

```js
var input = `2 | 4 | 6
2,070 | 4,140 | 6,210
1,544 | 3,087 | 4,631
5.0
127
1,200 :| 1,400
1,000 |: 1,167
5.1 |: 5.9`;

// Split string at new lines
var lines = input.split('\n');

// Save the table so we don't have to look it up each time
var $table = $('#the-table');

// Loop over de lines
$.each(lines, function(){
    var cells = this.split('|');

  // Open the new row
  var html = '<tr>';

  // Loop over de cells
  $.each(cells, function() {  
    var colspan = 1;

    if (this.charAt(0) == ':' || this.substr(this.length - 1) == ':') {
      // There's a : character inside this cell, make it span 2 colums
            colspan = 2;
        } else if (cells.length == 1) {
      // There's only one cell, make it the size of the table
        colspan = 42; // Arbitrary big number
    }

    // Add the cell
    html += '<td colspan="' + colspan + '">' + this.replace(/[: ]/g, '') + '</td>';
  });

  // Close the row
  html += '</tr>';

  // Append the row html we created into the table
  $table.append(html);
});
```

Comment: Re-read your question and noticed you can't divide the row in multiple <td>'s, do I understand that correctly?

Comment: Kapser - Thank you for putting that together - really appreciate the commenting along with it to help follow as well. You even covered the opposite condition flipping wide / narrow - although it's displaying : as content and I'm not sure the syntax to remove that :? https://jsfiddle.net/cmx5onea/2/

Comment: Using the Advanced Custom Fields - Table Field for a project, which will be easy for the user to input their own tables, but it only allows adding full rows / full columns, and the data entered needed to divide further as you've sorted out. Thanks again https://wordpress.org/plugins/advanced-custom-fields-table-field/

Comment: The question doesn't mention anything about Wordpress.

Comment: Updated the regex (the piece of code that replaces the `:` character when adding the cell). Now it should remove all instances of `:`. See https://jsfiddle.net/kapoko/cmx5onea/3/

Comment: Thank you Kapser, much appreciated. Yes, WordPress wasn't part of the question, just explaining the method of why there was no control for sub dividing those td cells on the user end since you had asked.

Comment: Kapser - sorry to bug you, but missed that the content was being pulled in through var input. The content will need to be pulled from inside the user entered td cells. How would this be converted to pulling the content from the table itself, then outputting? https://jsfiddle.net/cmx5onea/4/ #the-other-table

Comment: No problem :). Why don't you let users input as textarea instead of table in Advanced Custom Fields using your syntax?

Comment: I hear you - the end result is a table they are copying in from existing data sheets, so it makes more clear for the users in this case. Here's an updated Fiddle showing a broader table example: https://jsfiddle.net/cmx5onea/5/ I'm trying to scan through the td cells to then pass through your script, but having issues pulling the td cells into the lines variable.

Comment: You need some more jQuery for that. I'd love to help you out but don't have time at this moment, maybe later! Maybe brush up your jQuery knowledge and try yourself? [Maybe this will help?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36525042/how-to-get-the-contents-of-a-cell-in-a-table-using-jquery)

Comment: Trying to pull the td fields in with the same format used in your input variable, but can't get it to pull anything. Have a feeling it has something to do with the syntax, but could be in left field. https://jsfiddle.net/cmx5onea/6/

Comment: Hi Kapser - Thanks again for the help - I ended up going a different route and using PHP instead - I've updated the original question - your answer works great within a single column (as I had first asked the question), but since the user can enter multiple columns / rows, I needed a way to scan the td cells as entered as opposed to generating the table on the fly.

Comment: Sounds good! PHP seems like a logical way to go for this kind of problem :)